# Repeating list after post back form in ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some code retrieving the files from a folder using ASP.NET and C# and I display them using a CheckBoxList because the user will be able to select one of the files and then with a button at the end the user will have the ability to email that selected item.

The issue I am having is that after the item is selected and the email is sent, the page reloads and the items are duplicated and I am not sure why or how to corrected. Any help will be appreciate it.

The code is as follows:

```
if (File.Exists(wavFile))
                    {


                        ListItemCollection itemCollection = CheckBoxList2.Items;
                        itemCollection.Add(new ListItem(wavFile));
                        itemCollection.Add(new ListItem("<asp:Panel ID=\"Panel1\" runat=\"server\"><object id=\"MediaPlayer\" width=\"100\" height=\"42\" classid=\"CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95\" standby=\"Loading Windows Media Player components...\"" +
                                          "type=\"application/x-oleobject\"><param name=\"FileName\" value=\"" + wavFile + "\"><param name='AUTOPLAY' value='0'>" +
                                          "<embed type=\"application/x-mplayer2\" src=\"" + wavFile + "\" pluginspage=\"http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/\" name=\"MediaPlayer\" uimode=\"none\" width=\"300\" height=\"42\">" +
                                          "</embed></object></asp:Panel><br/><br/>"));
```

}

And then the email is control by a button with the following code:

```
protected void btnSend_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add("email@email.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress("email@email.com");
            mail.Subject = claimNumber.Text;
            mail.Body = "This is a test of the email again.";
            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
            attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(CheckBoxList2.SelectedValue);
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.email.com"; //Or Your SMTP Server Address
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
            ("email@email.com", "pa$$w0rd");

            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);

            this.labelSuccessIndex.Text = "<br/><strong>The file has been emailed.</strong>";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            labelError.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the code inside of `if (!Page.IsPostBack)`. This will stop it from executing when the page is posted back after the button click.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    if (File.Exists(wavFile))
    {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped! Don't forget to mark as answer so we can close this one out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the code in this block

```
if (File.Exists(wavFile))
```

is running at the first page load, than just wrap that block in another if

```
if(!Page.IsPostback) { if (File.Exists(wavFile))... }
```

That will prevent the code from adding to the list again.

If you are not populating the list on initial load, then you need some other way to avoid the second load, or clear the list and load all items every time.